# Python Open a User Created Text File

Tags: python, file

Considering there exists a manually user created text file named "roger.txt" and it contains "Tennis Roger Federer Armin" as its contents. Pickle can't open manually created files. Which packages can open manually created files in python so that when I run the code, I get the output as 'Tennis Roger Federer Armin'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in one line, wthout the context guard and optional file mode....

```
print open('roger.txt').read()
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do you need a package? Just read the file:

```
with open('roger.txt', 'r') as handle:
    print handle.read()
```